# Why does NSDictionary uses = sign inside json objects?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, xcode5

I am creating a new JSON (NSDictionary) object in Objective-C using various methods such

```
objectForKey
```

but when I actually print the NSDictionary object after converting it to NSString, I see that unlike the colon (:) separator, it uses the equals (=) separator between the key and value.

How can I ensure that the NSDictionary uses the : as a separator between the key and value?

Answer (score 1):

It is just a formatting issue. If you create an NSJSON obkect from it, that object will be in correctly formatter JSON. When you log NSDictionary to console or otherwise print it, it uses some custom formatting, probably unrelater to the actual internal structure.

Comment: I seaeched for this class NSJSON but couldnt find it. Did you really mean NSJSON class?

Comment: `NSJSONSerialization`